# Error while nesting two environments; Attempting to redefine \begin{equation*} and \begin{spit}; Command already defined?

Tags: macros, equations, environments, split

I'm trying to combine \begin{equation*} and \begin{split} into an abbreviated thing. Rather than doing this:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
      a = b & = b \\ & = b
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

I'd like to create some as follows:

```
    \fff a = b & = b \\ & = b 
    \endfff
```

I'm trying to use \newenvironment and \newcommand but its not working very nicely.

```
\newenvironment{placeholdername}
{\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
}
{ 
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}
}

\newcommand{\fff}{\begin{placeholdername}}
\newcommand{\endfff}{\end{placeholdername}}
```

Please excuse the my horrible naming scheme. I'm also getting an error that " Command \endfff is already defined", which makes no sense to me. I'm new to LaTeX by the way. Please help!

Comment: This won't work for the reasons David Carlisle says.  But your newenvironment defines `\placeholdername` and `\endplaceholdername`, so you could have made it `\newenvrinment{fff}` to begin with.  If it would have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but I don't think it's really useful. The idea here is to grab the whole contents and then do what you need to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{eqsplit*}{b}
 {\begin{equation*}\begin{split}#1\end{split}\end{equation*}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqsplit*}
  a & = b \\ & = c
\end{eqsplit*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not define commands starting with `\end` in LaTeX, as otherwise it would prevent defining the environment `fff`

Also for other reasons you can not hide AMS alignment environments in macros, `split` needs to grab its environment body so needs to scan ahead to find `\end{split}`The same is true of all AMS display constructs such as `align`, `gather` etc.

Note any reasonable editor will allow you to enter `\begin{equation}..\end{equation}` in two or three key strokes, or a menu option so defining abbreviated syntax does not save typing and makes it hard or impossible to get context sensitive syntax colouring or completion in your editor.